# Angular 2: open in new tab and store request url

Tags: angular, typescript, nancy

we are using a Angular 2 app with Typescript. Server is a lighweight NancyFX (C#) which is configured to response with a redirect to "/" if an unknown api call is done.

So what we are trying to do:
App is started, user is logged in. Now he wants to open a second tab, done by "open Link in a new tab" or with CTRL+Click.

The app is opened in a new tab again with some kind of a route URL (e.g. "/order/5"). The server responds with the redirect to "/" (the base angular route), the app starts, loads all angular stuff, is redirected to base route and checks if a token is available for the user and if yes -> it should redirect to the origin request URL

Problem: The original URL Request ("/order/5") is gone as the server only redirects to "/".

Is there ANY possibility to store the URL anyhow (e.g. in localstorage) so that the client knows where to redirect?

I read something about reading key/click events but this is all a little bit hacky..

The only way I see is to preserve the URL in Server Code, but this has to be done for each browser session separately OR with some kind of window.history but how should we know if this is a new session or just a page refresh??

We use default PathLocationStrategy.

Does anybody has an idea or is it just impossible?

UPDATE:
My Nancy Hosting Module

```
public HostingModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = o => Response.AsFile(Path.Combine(Response.RootPath, "index.html"));
        Get["/{ignored*}", ctx => ctx.Request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.Item1 == "text/html")] = o =>
            {
                return Response.AsFile(Path.Combine(Response.RootPath, "index.html"));

            };
    }
```

So all requests with text/html header should be accepted and return the default index.html.This works

BUT: the problem is that all files in index.html are requested relativ to origin path:
e.g.

First request: "foo.com/order/5" -> response index.html
-> after that the client starts to load all scripts in index.html
-> but as the request was foo.com/order/5 all scripts are tried to load like that:
foo.com/order/script1.js instead of foo.com/script1.js

-> So I only get a mess of 404 errors, or if I keep my redirect StatusCodehandler for 404 Errors it redirects the client to index.html again and again...

But thanks for help

Comment: Don't redirect to "/"

Comment: This will only result in 404 errors if the route is not explicitly defined in Nancy before the app is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

So you're redirecting to display the `index.html` which contains your angular app. The way I would solve this is by using 2 routes, the index route, and a greedy route that looks for the accept header with the value of `text/html` (which should be any browser request)

First route is:

```
Get("/", ...);
```

This is the index landing page.

The second route is using a greedy route:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#pattern

```
Get("/{ignored*}", ..., ctx => ctx.Request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.Item1 == "text/html"));
```

So any request that is not looking for html, it will return the default page. While anything from angular which should be looking accepting `application/json` will respond to all other queries.

Comment: Hm...maybe I don't get it right, but:
An Angular route is not a "order.html" but more than "order/5" -> This is normally handled by the internal router. But as soon as I start a new tab and enter a url like: "shop.com/order/5" -> server receives the request /because the angular app (and it's router) is not started yet. 

-> So the server would check if it is an HTML request -> NO -> check api calls -> NO -> return default index.html and the client would start the angular app. But the origin "order/5" request is gone...

Comment: Your angular app has a landing page right? Which is why you redirect to `/`, what i've written is a root route, and a catch-all (if not application/json) route, the purpose of catch all is to prevent you redirecting to `/` and just returning your default landing page which is the same as `/`

Comment: The catch all, will see that the request for `/order/5` is not accept `application/json` and will return the `index.html` page you use for `/`, then your angular app kicks in and requests `/order/5` from the route that accepts `application/json`

Comment: I hope that makes more sense @CabeSkuriles

Comment: So far I agree, but problem is now that the script files are called realtiv to the last route. I updated my opening post above.

Comment: @CabeSkuriles just make all scripts start from the root, prefix the script path with `/` so instead of `scripts/script1.js` you should do `/scripts/script1.js` this will make sure the path is always from the root of the domain.